# Как подключить pcap в Qt?

Tags: qt, pcap

Столкнулся с проблемой, создал простой консольный проект без qt в среде qt creator, скачал WinPcap dev tools, так же установил драйвер WinPcap. Забросил в папку с проектом файлы, прописал include,  но корректной работы так и не дождался. 
Подскажите, что можно сделать в этом случае?  Как то необходимо по особому подключить библиотеку?

Comment: Поясните, в чём вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д. Допустим: 1) Что подразумевается под корректной работой; 2) Какие действия должны приводить к корректной работе; 3) К чему эти действия привели на самом деле; Например так: запускаю приложение, должно открыться окошко, а выдается сообщение об ошибке с таким текстом: " ... ". Если вы добавите эту информацию в вопрос, скорее всего ответ найдется быстрее чем без нее.

Comment: Копирую пример из документации и сразу выдаёт ошибки типа undefined reference to `pcap_findalldevs' и не одну.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, проект не в состоянии найти библиотеку,  а у меня в свою очередь не хватает опыта подсказать как указать путь или дать указание на то что библиотека существует.